# How do you define a function with "while true" to make an incorrect user input to loop back to the start of the line on Python 3.8

Tags: python

So basically I'm pretty much new to python. The last time I tried learning python was version 5 or 6 (I kinda forgot) and unfortunately stopped learning it because of other irl things to focus on. Now I'm back but things seemed to have changed a bit on Python 3.8, And I need help!

Currently I'm trying to play around with user input where user inputs name and age. The problem I'm facing right now is with the age code lines, Im trying to make user put only intergers and when they put anything other than integer than it should loop back to original line. Currently, Im trying to use this:

```
def inputnumber(message):
    while true:
        try:
            userinput = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please input integers")
            continue
        else:
            return userinput
            break
```

The problem is basically python is bypassing all those codes and not outputting the message. I suspect it's my outdated use of codes from back at version 5 or 6.

Any of you got any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The only problem I see with this code is `true` instead of `True`.

Comment: Both `continue` and `break`, as written, are redundant; the loop will continue implicitly after the `try` statement completes, and `break` won't be reached because the `return` will immediately exit the function, terminating the loop as a side effect.

Comment: Also don't forget to call the function

Comment: Hi chepner and Chris_Rands. This is the OP, just wanna say thank you for your answers. It really helped me out! Turns out yes, it's the "true" statement that was wrong and also I forgot to call my function (my bad).... Anyways, thx again guys!